# In Symfony2, is there a gettable service that will return the list of registered Doctrine entity classes?

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine

In my config, I have `doctrine.orm.auto_mapping` set to true. So the Doctrine Bridge code is automatically looking in my bundle's Entity dir. Is there a gettable service that will return the list of registered entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$metaData = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
var_dump($metaData);
```